# Link Scala annotation in ScalaDoc

Tags: scala, scaladoc

In ScalaDoc I want to have a link to an annotation from a library: [discriminator](https://github.com/andyglow/scala-jsonschema/blob/db22e41bfb50ca29082dfc112210e61e8e677670/core/src/main/scala/json/schema/discriminator.scala).

My ScalaDoc:

```scala
/** Trait must be marked with [[json.schema.discriminator]] annotation. */
```

But ScalaDoc generation fails with the following error:

```scala
Could not find any member to link for "json.schema.discriminator".
```

UPD:
It appeared that errors were because of `-Xfatal-warnings` scalac option.

Once it got clear I found [sbt-api-mappings](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksInc/sbt-api-mappings) SBT plugin which resolves all external references with javadoc.io.

Comment: Sure, I have to do so because I use that annotation. Probably the issue here is that annotation (by Scala style) should start with lowercase letter.

Comment: Unfortunately no: discriminator annotations is in json.schema package. So I specify full name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't find it because you don't import the correct package.
Please note that the `json.schema.discriminator` class is part of the `"scala-jsonschema-core"` package.

Therefore you need to add to your `build.sbt`:

```
name := "StackOverflow"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.13.6"

libraryDependencies += "com.github.andyglow" %% "scala-jsonschema-core" % "0.7.6"
libraryDependencies += "com.github.andyglow" %% "scala-jsonschema-core" % "0.7.6" classifier "javadoc"
```

Then you can use it the same as you tried:

```
/** Trait must be marked with [[json.schema.discriminator]] annotation. */
```

[image]

Then `sbt doc` works:

[image]

Comment: And now it's more clear. Thank you. It appeared that I have -Xfatal-warnings scalac option enabled. Without it ScalaDoc is just a warning.